# What's the difference between saying "試験を受ける" and "試験を受験する"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, wago-and-kango

Recently I asked a question on HiNative and said "試験を受けました" but a native Japanese speaker corrected it to "試験を受験しました".

I'm positive I've seen someone say 試験を受ける before, so why did that native correct my sentence?

Comment: People have different thresholds for what they correct. Some people will correct anything to be the way they personally would have said it, not just corrections for things that are ungrammatical or unnatural. You would need to ask them.

Comment: 試験を受験する is redundant. 試験を受ける is just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

試験を受験する is a bit more formal than 試験を受ける, and more suitable for something like a university entrance examination. It implies an examination that is backed up by a formal institution, one with a big consequence, etc. You will probably need to specifically apply to be able to take it. It is less suitable for a routinely done test, something closer to a quiz at the end of a lesson.

Still, something like 大学入試を受ける is fine, too. The person who corrected it might have wanted to teach the word 受験する, nothing more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You answered very helpfully and clearly and were polite in your explanation